# Bootstrap 3, Dropdown problems

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3, and I have a navigation with this code.

```
   <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <style>
    body {
        padding-top: 120px;
    }
  </style>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

<div class="animbrand"><a class="navbar-brand" href="index">Home</a></div>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="portfolio"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span> Portfolio</a>

        </li>

        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></span> Music</a>

        </li>

    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span> Blog</a>

        </li>

    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Contact</a>

        </li>

      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>

          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span> Profile</a></li>

         </ul>
        </li>

       <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span></a>

       </li>

       </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is not with the code but with what happens. If I press the Glyphicon to go up (The up arrow the URL becomes index#) It shall take me up to the page, no problems there but then I cannot click on the drop downs until I go back onto my /index page.

http://i62.tinypic.com/1iyh38.png

http://i58.tinypic.com/2pqw9cm.png

Answer (score 0):

That's because you need an element with the `id` of '#', because when you click on the Link to go up, it will go to a page with the name of index#. So the way to fix this is put everything in a `div` with the id of # to refer to when you click on the `a` attribute. Or you can change the up button back to index to reload the page.

And you have all of your `a` tags going no where but back to the page.